# Provide Postman's environment config data to python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I have Postman's environment config file which looks next:

```
{
    "id": "some_id",
    "name": "env_name",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "host-key",
            "value": "url_1",
            "type": "text",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "host-key",
            "value": "url_2",
            "type": "text",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

How to privde these settings to python requests?
These settings in use for authentication.
I've found an article on http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/ about environment variables, but didn't get how to provide ready data. Or may be I've found incorrect article.

Comment: Are those supposed to be translated into HTTP parameters in Postman, which your server-side app would handle?  Or are you trying to translate a Postman collection to a Python client script?  In any case that's "just configuration" and you'd need some code to actually turn it into HTTP-level parameters; that's probably elsewhere in your Postman setup.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could load this postman config file into JSON object (This file is JSON look like so I assume Postman saves it as JSON). But you need to make sure it is **valid**. In your case, you have invalid comas in in two last but one brackets. You can validate JSON [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) function to load JSON from string. Then use it similar to python dicit.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open("config", "r") as f:
    conf_file = f.read()
    config = json.loads(conf_file)

pprint(config)
print(config["id"])
for value in config["values"]:
    print(value["key"])
    print(value["value"])
```

Output:

```
{u'id': u'some_id',
 u'name': u'env_name',
 u'values': [{u'enabled': True,
              u'key': u'host-key',
              u'type': u'text',
              u'value': u'url_1'},
             {u'enabled': True,
              u'key': u'host-key',
              u'type': u'text',
              u'value': u'url_2'}]}
some_id
host-key
url_1
host-key
url_2
```

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, with loading config file is ok. I did the same. But question is in how to provide these settings to python requests (API). For example I have endpoint with method POST for login:

```
https://some-api.com/api/session
{
  "user_login": "loginuser",
  "user_password": "passworduser"
}
```

And in Postman to become logged in I need to use Environment config. And how to be logged in using python requests. How to provide environment data into api requests?
For example:

```
requests.session().post("https://some-api.com/api/session", etc.)
```

P.S. modified commas error

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to pass this config data into python request method? Like let's say you have in this config 2 keys `{"user_login": "loginuser", "user_password": "passworduser"}` then in request use `request.session().post(url auth=(config['user_login'], config['user_password')` Is this what you need ?